# Deleting or removing the previous entity that was first created and saved when the method is executed again

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

```
      if ("LOCAL".equals(data.getCustGrp()) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(data.getTaxCd1())) {
        doCreateARDefaultTaxRecord("01", data.getTaxCd1(), data.getId().getReqId(), entityManager, true, true, true);
        doCreateARDefaultTaxRecord("11", data.getTaxCd1(), data.getId().getReqId(), entityManager, false, false, false);
        doCreateARDefaultTaxRecord("02", data.getTaxCd1(), data.getId().getReqId(), entityManager, false, false, false);
        doCreateARDefaultTaxRecord("07", data.getTaxCd1(), data.getId().getReqId(), entityManager, false, false, false);
        doCreateARDefaultTaxRecord("12", data.getTaxCd1(), data.getId().getReqId(), entityManager, false, false, false);
      } else {
        doCreateDefaultTaxRecord("", "1", data.getId().getReqId(), entityManager, true, true);
      }
```

I have the `if()` statement above in which it creates a single entry if it fails to meet the condition. However, when the user make changes from the UI, `if()` statement above will be executed again and check the conditions, if it now does meet the conditions, it now creates a set of predefined entries. BUT the problem is, the first entry that was created is there alongside with the predefined entries that was created after that.

Now, what I am trying to achieve is to delete the single entry that was created by `doCreateDefaultTaxRecord`. I have tried `entityManager.merge()` and `entityManager.remove()` but I still can't figure it out to work.

Are there any ways to implement the behavior? So that when it goes to execute `doCreateARDefaultTaxRecord`, it will first delete the single entry that has been created by `doCreateDefaultTaxRecord` and proceed to do the rest.

```
  private void doCreateARDefaultTaxRecord(String defaultTaxcd, String dataTaxCd, long reqId, EntityManager entityManager, boolean taxSepIndc,
      boolean contPntIndc, boolean cntryUse) {
    TaxInfoService taxService = new TaxInfoService();
    GeoTaxInfo taxInfo = new GeoTaxInfo();
    GeoTaxInfoPK taxInfoPK = new GeoTaxInfoPK();
    Admin reqAdmin = null;

    try {
      reqAdmin = new AdminService().getCurrentRecordById(reqId, entityManager);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOG.error("doCreateARDefaultTaxRecord : " + ex.getMessage());
      reqAdmin = new Admin();
    }

    if (taxService.getTaxInfoCountByReqId(entityManager, reqId) <= 4 && reqAdmin.getReqType().equalsIgnoreCase(CmrConstants.REQ_TYPE_CREATE)) {

      entityManager.remove(taxInfo);

      taxInfoPK.setReqId(reqId);
      taxInfoPK.setGeoTaxInfoId(taxService.generateGeoTaxInfoID(entityManager, reqId));

      taxInfo.setTaxCd(defaultTaxcd); /* predefined value */

      if (taxSepIndc) {
        taxInfo.setTaxSeparationIndc("07"); /* predefined value */
      } else {
        taxInfo.setTaxSeparationIndc("N"); /* predefined value */
      }

      if (cntryUse) {
        taxInfo.setCntryUse(""); /* predefined value */
      } else {
        taxInfo.setCntryUse("0000"); /* predefined value */
      }

      if (contPntIndc) {
        taxInfo.setContractPrintIndc(""); /* predefined value */
      } else {
        taxInfo.setContractPrintIndc("N"); /* predefined value */
      }

      taxInfo.setTaxNum(dataTaxCd);

      taxInfo.setCreateById(reqAdmin.getRequesterId());
      taxInfo.setCreateTs(SystemUtil.getCurrentTimestamp());
      taxInfo.setId(taxInfoPK);
      entityManager.merge(taxInfo);
      entityManager.flush();
    }
  }
```

```
  private void doCreateDefaultTaxRecord(String defaultBillingPrintIndc, String defaultTaxSepIndc, long reqId, EntityManager entMan, boolean indcFlag,
      boolean dumTaxCd) {
    TaxInfoService taxService = new TaxInfoService();
    GeoTaxInfo taxInfo = new GeoTaxInfo();
    GeoTaxInfoPK taxInfoPK = new GeoTaxInfoPK();
    Admin reqAdmin = null;
    try {
      reqAdmin = new AdminService().getCurrentRecordById(reqId, entMan);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOG.error("doCreateDefaultTaxRecord : " + ex.getMessage());
      reqAdmin = new Admin();
    }
    if (taxService.getTaxInfoCountByReqId(entMan, reqId) <= 0 && reqAdmin.getReqType().equalsIgnoreCase(CmrConstants.REQ_TYPE_CREATE)) {
      taxInfoPK.setReqId(reqId);
      taxInfoPK.setGeoTaxInfoId(taxService.generateGeoTaxInfoID(entMan, reqId));
      if (indcFlag) {
        taxInfo.setTaxSeparationIndc(defaultTaxSepIndc);
      } else {
        taxInfo.setTaxSeparationIndc(defaultTaxSepIndc);
        taxInfo.setBillingPrintIndc(defaultBillingPrintIndc);
      }
      taxInfo.setContractPrintIndc("");/* dummy value */
      taxInfo.setCntryUse("");/* dummy value */

      if (dumTaxCd) {
        taxInfo.setTaxCd("");/* dummy value */
      } else {
        taxInfo.setTaxCd("01");/* dummy value */
      }

      taxInfo.setTaxNum("");/* dummy value */
      
      taxInfo.setCreateById(reqAdmin.getRequesterId());
      taxInfo.setCreateTs(SystemUtil.getCurrentTimestamp());
      taxInfo.setId(taxInfoPK);
      entMan.persist(taxInfo);
      entMan.flush();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use entity manager to fetch the entity you want to delete and then call entity manager remove

```
// Fetch taxInfo using PK

GeoTaxInfoPK taxInfoPK = new GeoTaxInfoPK();
taxInfoPK.setReqId(id);
taxInfoPK.setGeoTaxInfoId(geoTaxInfoId);

GeoTaxInfo taxInfo = entityManager.find(GeoTaxInfo.class, taxInfoPK);

// Delete taxInfo

entityManager.remove(taxInfo);
```